# Discrepancy between prescribed rules and de facto practice

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What words or phrases are useful with regard to a situation where rules are formally debated and become mandatory while actual practice continues independently?

I'm thinking of something other than anarchism, and more along the lines of a false regime that creates ineffective regulations purely because that is its function. Meanwhile, actual behaviour is successfully governed by social pressure and interaction rather than adherence to the official rules.

Comment: It's unclear if you want words for the question at the top or about anarchism or some other dichotomy?  Discrepancy is a good one. Dichotomy, too, in fact. Inconsistency, disparity, polarity, conflict....

Comment: I think **reality** covers this. Otherwise, we'd need no police.

Comment: Voting with their feet means that people shop where they want, leave when they can, and drive faster than the road sign demands -- but only by a small factor that all other drivers adhere to.

Comment: Fyi, "De jure" means "by law" in contrast to "de facto".

Answer (score 2):

There's a saying:  **you can't legislate morality.**

[Dr. Martin Luther King](http://www.letterstotheexiles.com/hearts-habits-men-mlk-law-morality/) had this to say on the battle between laws and morality:

> It may be true that you can’t legislate integration, but you can
>   legislate desegregation. It may be true that morality cannot be
>   legislated, but behavior can be regulated. It may be true that the law
>   cannot change the heart, but it can restrain the heartless. It may be
>   true that the law can’t make a man love me, but it can restrain him
>   from lynching me, and I think that’s pretty important also. So while
>   the law may not change the hearts of men, it does change the habits of
>   men. And when you change the habits of men, pretty soon the attitudes
>   and the hearts will be changed. And so there is a need for strong
>   legislation constantly to grapple with the problems we face.

A more legal term I also suggest is **[customs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custom_(law)) versus positive law**:

> Custom in law is the established pattern of behavior that can be
>   objectively verified within a particular social setting. A claim can
>   be carried out in defense of "what has always been done and accepted
>   by law." Related is the idea of prescription; a right enjoyed through
>   long custom rather than positive law.
>
> Customary law (also, consuetudinary or unofficial law) exists where:
>   1.a certain legal practice is observed and
>   2.the relevant actors consider it to be law (opinio juris).
>
> Most customary laws deal with standards of community that have been
>   long-established in a given locale.

As mentioned in the above, other terms are *prescription*, *consuetudinary law*, *unofficial law*, *opinio juris*, and *community standards*, any/all of which can be opposed to *positive law*.

Comment: There is also contract law, meritime law, merchant law, natural law, and more bodies of law between persons.

Comment: @Jordan Jelinek yes, nice additions!  Upvoting your answer.  The list is probably quite long, lol.